# Blur images in Windows Runtime C# using WriteableBitmapEx

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to blur an image in my new Windows Phone Runtime C# app (WPRT)
I used WriteableBitmapEx NuGet and this code to make my image blured but can't see any changes in my picture . what's going wrong guys ?

```
public TestXaml()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ....
        test();
    }
async void test()
    {
        var ImgFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/TestBG.jpg"));
        var wb = new WriteableBitmap(100,100);
        using (var strm = await ImgFile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            wb = await wb.FromStream(strm);
        }
        var wb3 = WriteableBitmapExtensions.Convolute(wb, WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur5x5);

        ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
        ib.ImageSource = wb3;
        PageBackground.Background = ib;
    }
```

also I tried WriteableBitmapExtensions.KernelGaussianBlur3x3 but still no change

Comment: Looks like you need to set ImageSource to wb3 instead of wb.

Comment: ow sorry , first I tried wb3 I seems there's no change I tried wb too but didn't see any change . I forgot to change it back . now I edit post . I can't get blured pictures even in wb3 . the only change I can see is a little delay in changing page background

Comment: Thanks man , seems my images were not good to use blur on them and this code works but is it possible to change value of this blur effect ? for example I want to blur my picture more than 5x5 that used inn this lib . Is it possible ?

Comment: Isn't it possible to get deeper blur effect ? It's not enough for me